# Why does Postgresql say "schema does not exist"

Tags: postgresql

How can i get this query to work?

```
SELECT weather.id, cities.name, weather.date, weather.degree
FROM weather JOIN weather.city_id ON cities.id
WHERE weather.date = '2011-04-30';
```

ERROR: schema "weather" does not exist.

weather is not schema, it's a table!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

perhaps:

```
SELECT weather.id, cities.name, weather.date, weather.degree 
FROM weather JOIN cities ON (weather.city_id = cities.id)
WHERE weather.date = '2011-04-30';
```

postgres is complaining about the join on `weather.city_id` which is interpreted as a table/view called 'city_id' in schema 'weather'