# Nested JSON from Postgres API, schema does not exist?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a SQL API to my Postgres database that returns JSON.

I have two tables: `holidays`, which has a schema of `name`, `hd_id`. And `photos`, which are photos take on that day. Its schema is `url`, `caption`, `h_id`.

I'd like to create a nested json object like the one down below. The SQL I'm running is

```
    SELECT holidays.name, holidays.h_id, 
    concat('[', group_concat(concat('{"src":"', photos.url, '","caption":"', photos.caption '"}', separater ','), ']') ) 
    FROM holidays 
    INNER JOIN photos 
    ON holidays.h_id = photos.h_id 
    GROUP BY holidays.h_id
```

But that gives me the error `"schema "photos" does not exist"`. Photos is a table, not a schema. I don't seem to be making the same mistake as [this seemingly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829865/postgresql-query-problem-schema-does-not-exist). I'm not sure how else to structure the JOIN.

Here's the desired JSON output.

```
   [
    {
        name: 'Labor Day',
        h_id: 'a1',
        photos: [
            {
                src: 'url',
                caption: 'text'
            },
            {
                src: 'url',
                caption: 'text'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'MLK Day',
        h_id: 'a2',
        photos: [
            {
                src: 'url',
                caption: 'text'
            },
            {
                src: 'url',
                caption: 'text'
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
```

Comment: It looks like Postgres [does not have group_concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `group_concat` in `PostgreSQL`. You may use [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select
    h.name, h.h_id, 
    '[' || string_agg('{"src":"' || p.url || '", "caption":"' || p.caption  || '"}', ',') || ']'
from holidays as h
    inner join photos as p on h.h_id = p.h_id 
group by h.name, h.h_id
```

see [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f7afe/8) with this example

Or use [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). There's also nice JSON support in [version 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: That works thanks! I ended up adding "AS children" after the string_agg line (the third line in your answer code) so that the returned column has a nice name.